# Can I use vlcj library in an Applet?

Tags: java, video, applet, streaming, vlcj

How can I use vlcj-1.2.0 to play a video file in an applet if I need libvlc.dll from user's VLC folder in Program_Files?

Can I load the native library from the applet? Or can I use the firefox VLC plugin?
Or do you know any other solution?

Comment: You can use native libraries in applets if they are signed (and the user accepts the question dialog). You will need JNI or JNA to access the VLC lib (or any Java library which does this).

Comment: About accessing the browser's plugin, I have no idea - maybe if the plugin provides some Javascript API? (But then the video will not be played *in* the applet, only steered by it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include the native library with the applet (you don't need VLC installed to use vlcj as long as you have libvlc.dll/so and associated plugins) then you should be able to use it, but only if it's signed.

If you just want to play video on the server though, a much simpler solution would be to save all the videos as FLV and then use flash to play them back. Or HTML5 of coruse!